# Programmatically stop a PlayFramework Job

Tags: asynchronous, interrupt, playframework-1.x, jobs

I am trying to programmatically stop a running Job in PlayFramework. When a Job is run, I save the 'Promise' object that it returns when it's started. This object has a 'cancel' method that SHOULD cancel a scheduled job OR stop an existing job, however it doesn't seem to do anything.

What other way is there to stop a running Job?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement well-ordered cancellation yourself. `cancel` won't just end the thread's execution as this may cause undesired results. The solution is similar too how `Thread.stop()` is deprecated and `Thread.interrupt()` should be used instead.

Check if the job got cancelled at occasion. If you are running heavy calculation in a loop, check if it still should continue running at the beginning. You can even return partial results this way.

Comment: The problem is the 'Job' in PlayFramework isn't a thread in itself and I need to interrupt it from the outside of the thread it's running on. I don't want to implement a 'check whether it should be running' type of pattern since it may not exit if it's stuck in a loop for some reason. An interrupt exception would have a little more success there.

Comment: @Iv4n What Job and Future/Promise implementations are you using exactly? There are quite a few different ones for java, scala, play1, play2 and akka. If you are using Play 2.x there should be some way to run futures with a timeout if you worry about being stuck in a loop.

Comment: I'm using Play 1.x - Java only.

Comment: I had a similar situation and unfortunately had to resort to a "check" type of pattern. Mine had to deal with cancelling a job from the browser and I couldn't think of a way to be sure that the cancel is sent to the correct web server considering our site is balance loaded. The phrase "if it's stuck in a loop for some reason" scares me though, you may want to take some time to think about why you would ever be stuck in a loop like that and put checks before this loop.